# Calculate variations on a string

Tags: c#, permutation

I have a series of incorrectly encoded base36 values - these were encoded from integers using a string of letters, missing the "i" and "o". They now need to be converted back to integers using C#.

There are multiple permutations because of the rollover effect.

"0" can either equal 0 or 34;
"1" can either equal 1 or 35.

So, for instance, if I have a string "a110", it has six possible values.

I'm having a hard time trying to figure how to code for this.
All the examples I've looked at compute variations for a set of elements, for example

```
char[] = { a, b, c }
int[] = { 1, 2, 3 }
```

However, in my case, there are conditionals involved too, and it's making my head hurt. Can anyone help?

Comment: the transformation is non-unique, and conversion back may involve ambiguities, so I doubt if this is practically usable.

Comment: `a110` would actually have 8 possible values: `10,1,1,0`, `10,1,1,34`, `10,1,35,0`, `10,1,35,34`, `10,35,1,0`, `10,35,1,34`, `10,35,35,0`, `10,35,35,34`.  It's certainly possible to code to give you all possible results, but as @David said, it's probably not going to give you a *usable* result.

Comment: @David It might not be practically useful but this might just be used to make a list for human inspection, whereby someone is choosing the one they know to be right.

Comment: "I have a number that has accidentally been multiplied by zero. How do I get back my original number, from before the multiplication?" _You can't._ Was there any redundancy in the data? What do the values represent. For example if you have an English text where all `Y` and `Z` have become `A` and `B`, respectively, you can often guess from context if a particular occurence of `A` comes from a "real" `A`, or from a `Y`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I think this is a different situation than multiplying by 0. The data are not *wrong* they're just mangled. The right answer is in there somewhere within a relatively small (and importantly) finite set of possibilities.

Comment: @Brad Well, it's exponential in the length of the data. For every time we have 36 values, the expectation is that 4 of them are ambiguous. That's one ninth. So if the data consists of, say, 1000 values, the finite set you mention is `Math.Pow(2, 111)`. My number that I accidentally lost, was just an `Int32`, so there was much fewer possibilities. 1000 base-36 values correspond to 5 kilobytes.

Comment: (Sorry, that was 5 kilobits, or circa 650 bytes.)

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen With a 1000 character string, yes that is a huge number of possibilities. But if all the base-36 strings are, say, 10 characters the suddenly the average number of possible strings generated from each original string is 2^(`#ambiguous characters in string`) where `#ambiguous characters in string` = `characters in string` * `4/36` (odds of being ambiguous). that's 2.1 possibilities generated on average. If your strings are 20 characters it jumps to ~4. If you have 100 characters then, yes, it's like 2200 possibilities which is...a lot. but a smaller string is doable.

Comment: @Brad I agree completely. But most of the time when people care to use base-36 encoding, they have more than 100 characters. Otherwise there would be little need for such an encoding, I think.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen yeah, very good point. I guess there *is an answer* to this question, whether is is practical or not is up to the OP.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen the max string length I'm dealing with is 4 characters, so we're talking about 16 possibilities at most in each case. There is secondary information which will allow me to figure out which conversion is correct. very practical. But I still can't figure out the structure of the code to actually do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it with the following code. It was actually a little simpler than I expected, since I only had two conditions, and two options. It uses recursion and steps through each character in the string. If that character is a 0 or 1, it then diverges, and continues building the string.

It actually generates a few duplicates, so I had to add a condition to only add it to the string list if it doesn't already exist. If someone else can point me to slightly better logic I'd appreciate it

```
public string st = "101"; // hardcoded for now
public char[] cs;
public List<string> variations;

static void Main()
{
    cs = st.ToCharArray();
    variations = new List<string>();
    vary("",0);
}

static void vary(string m, int n)
{     
    for (int i = n; i < cs.Count(); i++)
    {
        if (cs[i] == '0' || cs[i] == '1')
        {
            // recurse
            combo(m + (cs[i] == '0' ? "0" : "1"), i + 1);
            combo(m + (cs[i] == '0' ? "Y" : "Z"), i + 1);
        }
        m += cs[i];
    }
    if(!variations.Contains(m))
        variations.Add(m);
}
```

for the string "101" I get the following combinations

```
101
10Z
1Y1
1YZ
Z01
Z0Z
ZY1
ZYZ
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compute the list of all possible input strings. First, read the input into a list of ints. Now, you know that each of those (if it's a sufficiently low value) could be one of two things. So then you can create an enumerator that returns all of the possible inputs, via a recursive descent.